# Having a System tray in a Console Application with a menu in C#

Tags: c#, console-application, system-tray

I've scoured this site and numerous other resources for trying to track this down.

I have a console application that I am trying to get have a system tray icon for.

That part works.

What I cannot actually get to work is adding a menu to it when I right click. I really just need an exit button that will shut it down.

My entire class is fairly small so I will include it. I have initialized this object in my main method and thats pretty much all I need since I drive this from the constructor. I've found resource that indicated I would not need a click event but I've tried both so Im not exactly sure.

I've tried patching this together from other resources but everyone seems to have a slightly different problem or I'm missing something.

Thanks for taking a look.

```
namespace PvsMessageLogger
{
  public class SystemTray
  {
    private readonly string _systemDisplayName;
    private readonly NotifyIcon _systemTray;
    public SystemTray(string systemDisplayName)
    {
      _systemTray = new NotifyIcon();
      _systemDisplayName = systemDisplayName;
      InitializeSystemTray();
    }

    private void InitializeSystemTray()
    {
      _systemTray.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
      _systemTray.Visible = true;
      _systemTray.BalloonTipTitle = _systemDisplayName;
      _systemTray.BalloonTipText = _systemDisplayName + " is running in the background";
      MenuItem[] menuList = {new MenuItem("Exit", (s, e) => Application.Exit()) };

      ContextMenu clickMenu = new ContextMenu(menuList);
      _systemTray.ContextMenu = clickMenu;
      _systemTray.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817468/system-tray-icon-with-c-sharp-console-application-wont-show-menu)

Comment: A fundamental requirement for NotifyIcon is running a message loop.  It is the only way that the OS can deliver notifications.  You could start another thread and have it call Application.Run().

Comment: @HansPassant why start another thread?

Comment: Anybody that tries it will discover why.  Call Application.Run() on the main thread and it is just not a console app anymore.  You might as well start with the Winforms template and change the Output type setting to "Console", that's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer in another thread, you must add Application.Run() after you create the icon.

You can find more details on Roman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817468/system-tray-icon-with-c-sharp-console-application-wont-show-menu).

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thanks.